# How to access data properly?

Tags: xetex

I have a class which defines the following:

```
% myclass.cls
\newcommand*{\name}[2]{\def\@firstname{#1}\def\@lastname{#2}}
\newcommand*{\firstname}[1]{\def\@firstname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\lastname}[1]{\def\@lastname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\familyname}[1]{\def\@lastname{#1}}
\def\@familyname{\@lastname}
```

I am using it as follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{myclass}

%other aspects here
\input{common_personal.tex}
\begin{document}
\value{name}
```

In `common_personal.tex`, I am providing values as follows:

```
\name{Amitav}{Mohanty}
```

I expect the name to show up but `\value{name}` does not put the value of `name` in the document. How can I do it correctly? I am open to suggestions around arranging files as well.

Comment: `\value` provides an integer representation of the argument, which needs to be a **counter**.  There is no `name` counter in your class, it would seem.  You might need `\csname @firstname\endcsname{} \csname @lastname\endcsname` to see the name, unless your class provides a better way, not shown by you.  In essence, the invocation of `\name` stores data into two macros, `\@firstname` and `\@lastname`, which are not directly accessible to user code, unless you change the catcode of `@` or use `\csname` constructs.

Comment: that worked. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The fundamental misunderstanding of the OP revolves around the meaning of `\value`.  Unlike the way in which the OP seems to indicate, `\value` does not provide the substitution text of a macro of a given name.  Rather, `\value` provides an integer representation of the argument, which needs to be the name of a counter.

A typical usage would be as part of a mathematical `\ifnum` comparison.  For example,

```
\ifnum\value{equation}=3\relax Do something if Eq 3
\else Do something if not Eq 3\fi
```

In this case, `equation` is a counter associated with the equation count in a document.  If we look at the `\name` macro that the OP seems focused on, we see it is a macro, not a counter, so `\value{name}` has no legitimate meaning.

If we look at what `\name` actually does, it sets the values of two other macros, based upon its two arguments.  The macro names where the data are stored are `\@firstname` and `\@lastname`.  However, because the two macros have a `@` in their name, they cannot, by default, be accessed by user code, because the catcode of `@` during class/package definition is different (11) than it is during user code execution (12).

To access these macro values with user code, the user has two options.  One is to use a `\csname` syntax, as in `\csname @firstname\endcsname` and `\csname @lastname\endcsname`.  The other is to change the catcode of `@` (temporarily) in the user code.  This latter approach is done with `\makeatletter` to make the catcode of `@`=11, and `\makeatother` to make the catcode of `@`=12.

The invocation of these two `\makeat...` macros should, generally, surround the *macro definition* in which `@` macro names are being referenced.  If these `@` macro names are being used directly, outside of a macro, then the `\makeat...` commands can surround the `@` macro directly, as in `\makeatletter\@firstname{} \@lastname\makeatother`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to also define wrappers for delivering the data.

When you do `\name{Amitav}{Mohanty}`, you are doing

```
\def\@firstname{Amitav}
\def\@lastname{Mohanty}
```

and TeX knows nothing more. As explained in Steven's answer, `\value` is a reserved kernel command that's used to access the value of a counter.

Let's assume you need to access the name in order to print it, say as argument to `\author` or whatever else; maybe you also need to access the last name or first name only.

You can set up some commands for the purpose. Inside `myclass.cls` you can do

```
\newcommand{\usedata}[1]{\csname @usedata@#1\endcsname}
\newcommand{\@usedata@fullname}{\@firstname\space\@lastname}
\newcommand{\@usedata@firstname}{\@firstname}
\newcommand{\@usedata@lastname}{\@lastname}
```

so in the document you can do

```
\usedata{fullname}
\usedata{firstname}
\usedata{lastname}
```

The idea is that `\usedata` builds a control sequence out of its argument and you can freely define the commands for these concatenations. For instance

```
\usedata{firstname}
```

will become

```
\csname @usedata@firstname\endcsname
```

which is equivalent to calling `\@firstname` as it results from the definition and here's where the first name has been stored.